# Android floating action button with drag-drop functionality

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

How to implement Drag and drop with floating action button in Android like flipkart application

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is pretty broad -- if you provide more specifics, it would help us answer the question. Also, do you have specific code you can post?

Comment: And you can also look at the "Related" questions (in the sidebar on the right-hand side of this page).

Comment: This is not broad question. I mentioned just like flipkart application not same , drag and drop functionality with fab

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this question. It wasn't me.

Comment: I've upvoted the question to cancel out the -1.

Comment: Also, some more questions on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+drag+and+drop

Comment: is anybody find out solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop functionality for fab around the screen can be achieved using the setOnTouchListener and listening events,please try below code

```
fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            float startX;
            float startRawX;
            float distanceX;
            int lastAction;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        startRawX = event.getRawX();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + startX);
                        view.setY(event.getRawY() + startX);

                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        distanceX = event.getRawX()-startRawX;
                        if (Math.abs(distanceX)< 10){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAB CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Draggable Floating Action Buttton:

```
 fabCreate = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
 fabCreate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                  dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                  lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                  break;

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
                  view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                  lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                  break;

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                      //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:
                  intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity1.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              default:
                  return false;
          }
          return true;
      }
  });
```

Comment: how about onLongClickListener and onDragListener ?